# Redis DB backup and restore?

Tags: redis

Is there any reliable backup & restore method, tool, ... for Redis DB ?

been googling around couples of hours and there was nothing just copy the dump file `/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb` or some scripts that uses MIGRATE (idk if this even count as backup)

Ok lets say there is Redis DB (big one) and its Windows version of Redis
[github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases)

so we need a copy of this DB in other branch of company that uses final Linux  version of Redis, cuz windows version is outdated and its performance is not good as Linux version.

all keys and values are encrypted and stored as binary format in Redis, so is there any reliable backup & restore for Redis DB ?

Comment: i guess there are two ways...try to copy the rdb and see if it works. If it doesn't work, then run a program which scans all the keys in the windows redis and 'migrates with copy option' to the linux redis.

Comment: yeah its plan A! copying Windows dump to Linux worked on my local PC, and from Linux to Windows failed. but still its not reliable you know what i mean. looking for plan B and C in worst cases

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions around that helps you automate this process.

Making a Redis backup is quite simple though:

1. Review / update your Redis configuration.
2. Create a snapshot for your Redis data (known as a "dump"/"rdb file").
3. Save the RDB file to a remote location

To create the snapshot (2) you'll need to use `redis-cli` `SAVE`or `BGSAVE`command.

You'll then need to create a little script (you can find one [here](https://simplebackups.com/blog/the-complete-redis-backup-guide-with-examples/)) to transfer your `.rdb` file to a remote storage (like AWS S3).

You can then automate all of that using CRON.

Of course, you can now use services like [SimpleBackups](https://simplebackups.com/redis-backup/) to get all of that done for you.